# EC2 spark master instance size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I intend to setup spark cluster on EC2. How much resources spark master instance actually needs? Since master is not involved in processing any of the tasks can it be the smallest EC2 instance?

Comment: It's best to try and see what works.

Comment: I assume that you are planning on using Spark's standalone clustering rather than running over Yarn or Mesos.  Is that right?  I think that this can be a relatively small instance, but I suspect that you might run into memory issues if you run on the smallest EC2 instance size (T2 micro which has 1GB of RAM).  @DanielDarabos is probably right. Try it and see what happens.  You can always change to a larger instance type.

Comment: @DemetriKots Thanks, and you're correct I want to use standalone mode accessing attached EBS shared among instances, no HDFS.

Answer (score 1):

This obviously depends on what kinds of jobs you're planning to run, how big is the cluster etc, so in that sense the advice to simply try different configurations is good. However, in my purely personal experience the driver instance should be at least at the level of the slave instances. This is mainly due to two reasons.

First of all, there are times when you need the result of the job in a single place. Maybe you just don't want to spend time combining files, maybe you need the results in some specific order which would be hard to achieve in a distributed way etc. but this means the driver should be able to hold all the data (as rdd.collect gathers the results to the driver instance).

Second of all, many of the shuffle-based operations seem to require a lot of memory from the driver. I'm not exactly sure about the details of why this happens (if anyone knows, please do share) but I can't count the number of times I've seen reduceyKey causing an out of memory error from the driver.

Answer (score -2):

---

**Edit:** I have assumed you were using *Spark*'s `spark-ec2` script, which I believe does install the *NameNode* in the master instance. If the *NameNode* is not installed at the master intance, however, my answer has no validity as correctly pointed by *@DemetriKots* in the comments.

---

Although the *master* instance is not involved in data processing, it plays a major role during the management of the workload and resource allocation, e.g (all info is taken from the sources):

- [NameNode](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/NameNode)

> The NameNode is the centerpiece of an HDFS file system. It keeps the directory tree of all files in the file system, and tracks where across the cluster the file data is kept. It does not store the data of these files itself.
>
> Client applications talk to the NameNode whenever they wish to locate a file, or when they want to add/copy/move/delete a file. The NameNode responds the successful requests by returning a list of relevant DataNode servers where the data lives.

[This](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDP2Alpha/index.htm#Hardware_Recommendations_for_Hadoop.htmhttp://docs.hortonworks.com/HDP2Alpha/index.htm#Hardware_Recommendations_for_Hadoop.htm) (look for *Hardware Recommendations for Hadoop* on the left index) *Hortonworks* document specifies some recommendations for the master instance in a *Hadoop* cluster. While it might not be adequate for the slave instances (due to *Spark*'s memory usage), I would say it can be useful in the case of the master instance in a *Spark* cluster.

Comment: This answer seems to be about a combination of HDFS and Hadoop MapReduce.  The question was specifically about setting up a Spark cluster.  The spark master instance does not need to be the same machine as the NameNode so it is not clear how this is relevant, and the MR JobTracker has nothing to do with Spark.

Comment: I assumed the OP would be using *Spark*'s `spark-ec2`, which I believe it does install the NameNode on the same instance as the master. If that was the case, some of the stated above could still be useful. However, I agree that the *JobTracker* has nothing to do with *Spark* at all (removed from answer).